# Class Values on WaitMsg

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Out text team would like a **class/cls** value on the **waitMsg** panel that pops up while uploading a file in our form.

```
handler: function(){
    fs.getForm().submit({url:url, waitMsg:'Uploading Data...'});
}
```

Is it possible to do this on the waitMsg?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please try adding the following once.

```
handler: function(){
    fs.getForm().submit({url:url, waitMsg:'Uploading Data...',msgCls:'yourmsgclass'});
}
```

For more info check the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-cfg-msgCls)